# How to keep 3 columns from breaking when resizing

Tags: html, css, layout, break

So basically, i'm trying to create a 3 column website. Everything looks good until i resize the window and then the third column breaks out of design and goes to the next line. I did check on Stackoverflow and found a slight help, which was to code-in a min-width for the body tag but the problem is that i get a horizontal scrollbar.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance. And feel free to correct any of my coding structure!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
<title>My Webpage</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: white;
    min-width: 960px; margin: 0 auto;
}

.header {
    font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: rgb(135, 219, 51);
    margin: 0;
    padding: 20px;
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

.header p {
    font-family:'Franklin Gothic Medium', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, sans-serif;
        }

.navigation {
          }

ul {
    background-color: rgb(183, 255, 0);
list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;       
        }

        li {float: left;
        
    }

li a {
    display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 14px 16px;

    
}

a:hover {
    background-color: rgb(43, 226, 98);
}

.column p::first-letter {
  color:  rgb(183, 255, 0);
  font-size: xx-large;
  
}

.column {
  width: 30%;
  float: left;
  background-color: rgb(245, 245, 245);
 padding-left: 14px;
 padding-right: 14px;
 margin: 5px 15px;
 border-radius: 25px;
  border: 2px solid #73AD21;
 
   
 
}

.maincontent {
    box-sizing:content-box
    width: 100%;
  
  
}

.column p{
   
    text-align: justify;
 
    
   
}

.column h2{
  color:  rgb(183, 255, 0);;  
margin: 0;
padding-top: 14px;
}

.column:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}


@media screen and (max-width:600px) {
  .column {
    width: 100%;
  }

 






</style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="header">
            <h1>Header</h1>
            <p>orem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas sit amet pretium urna. Vivamus</p>
        </div>

        <div class="navigation">
            <ul>
                <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <main>
            <div class="maincontent">
            <div class="column">
                <h2>Column</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas sit amet pretium urna. Vivamus venenatis velit nec neque ultricies, eget elementum magna tristique. Quisque vehicula, risus eget aliquam placerat, purus leo tincidunt eros, eget luctus quam orci in velit. Praesent scelerisque tortor sed accumsan convallis.</p>
            </div>

            <div class="column">
                <h2>Column</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas sit amet pretium urna. Vivamus venenatis velit nec neque ultricies, eget elementum magna tristique. Quisque vehicula, risus eget aliquam placerat, purus leo tincidunt eros, eget luctus quam orci in velit. Praesent scelerisque tortor sed accumsan convallis.</p>
            </div>

            <div class="column">
                <h2>Column</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas sit amet pretium urna. Vivamus venenatis velit nec neque ultricies, eget elementum magna tristique. Quisque vehicula, risus eget aliquam placerat, purus leo tincidunt eros, eget luctus quam orci in velit. Praesent scelerisque tortor sed accumsan convallis.</p>
            </div>
        </div>


        </main>


        
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you are doing this just for learning purpose then fine else instead of reinventing the wheel you can explore Bootstrap Framework for responsive design

Comment: Hey mate, cheers for the response. I am able to fix the problem by copying others codes (already done) but i can't work-out why its happening when i code by hand. I just want to be able to fully control my codes, if you know what i mean.

Answer (score 0):

You can prevent the column from collapsing by using `display: flex` on your `.maincontent` element:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>My Webpage</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <style>
      * {
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    
    body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      background-color: white;
      min-width: 960px;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }
    
    .header {
      font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
      text-align: center;
      background-color: rgb(135, 219, 51);
      margin: 0;
      padding: 20px;
      color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    }
    
    .header p {
      font-family: 'Franklin Gothic Medium', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, sans-serif;
    }
    
    .navigation {}
    
    ul {
      background-color: rgb(183, 255, 0);
      list-style-type: none;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    
    li {
      float: left;
    }
    
    li a {
      display: block;
      color: white;
      text-align: center;
      text-decoration: none;
      padding: 14px 16px;
    }
    
    a:hover {
      background-color: rgb(43, 226, 98);
    }
    
    .column p::first-letter {
      color: rgb(183, 255, 0);
      font-size: xx-large;
    }
    
    .column {
      width: 30%;
      float: left;
      background-color: rgb(245, 245, 245);
      padding-left: 14px;
      padding-right: 14px;
      margin: 5px 15px;
      border-radius: 25px;
      border: 2px solid #73AD21;
    }
    
    .maincontent {
      box-sizing: content-box width: 100%;
      display: flex;
    }
    
    .column p {
      text-align: justify;
    }
    
    .column h2 {
      color: rgb(183, 255, 0);
      ;
      margin: 0;
      padding-top: 14px;
    }
    
    .column:after {
      content: "";
      display: table;
      clear: both;
    }
    
    @media screen and (max-width:600px) {
      .column {
        width: 100%;
      }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="header">
    <h1>Header</h1>
    <p>orem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas sit amet pretium urna. Vivamus</p>
  </div>

  <div class="navigation">
    <ul>
      <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <main>
    <div class="maincontent">
      <div class="column">
        <h2>Column</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas sit amet pretium urna. Vivamus venenatis velit nec neque ultricies, eget elementum magna tristique. Quisque vehicula, risus eget aliquam placerat, purus leo tincidunt eros, eget
          luctus quam orci in velit. Praesent scelerisque tortor sed accumsan convallis.</p>
      </div>

      <div class="column">
        <h2>Column</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas sit amet pretium urna. Vivamus venenatis velit nec neque ultricies, eget elementum magna tristique. Quisque vehicula, risus eget aliquam placerat, purus leo tincidunt eros, eget
          luctus quam orci in velit. Praesent scelerisque tortor sed accumsan convallis.</p>
      </div>

      <div class="column">
        <h2>Column</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas sit amet pretium urna. Vivamus venenatis velit nec neque ultricies, eget elementum magna tristique. Quisque vehicula, risus eget aliquam placerat, purus leo tincidunt eros, eget
          luctus quam orci in velit. Praesent scelerisque tortor sed accumsan convallis.</p>
      </div>
    </div>


  </main>



</body>

</html>
```

Comment: wicked!!! That works. Interesting how everything stretches downwards. Nonetheless, stick a work around. Wonder if there are any out more out there?

Comment: Update: The input you provided works well but breaks the @media screen and (max-width:600px) { tag and the website stops becoming responsive.

Answer (score 0):

It happens because you write the

```
  @media screen and (max-width:600px) {.column {
width: 100%;}
```

So the column section will consume 100% of its parents (maincontent) size. Each column is 100% maincontent size, thats why the next column will be place at the bottom of the previous one.
If you wanna make the column adjustable to the width of your screen. Just set the

```
.column{ 
width : 31%}
```

and remove the responsive option for column.
31% is optional (if its not enough you can redice or add it).

Answer (score 0):

```
enter code here
```

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

.header {
    font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: rgb(135, 219, 51);
    margin: 0;
    padding: 20px;
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

.header p {
    font-family:'Franklin Gothic Medium', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, sans-serif;
        }

.navigation {
          }

ul {
    background-color: rgb(183, 255, 0);
list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;       
        }

        li {float: left;
        
    }

li a {
    display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 14px 16px;

    
}

a:hover {
    background-color: rgb(43, 226, 98);
}

.column p::first-letter {
  color:  rgb(183, 255, 0);
  font-size: xx-large;
  
}
main{
margin:10px;

}
.column {
  float: left;
  width: 32.33%;
  padding: 20px;
  height: 300px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  border: 2px solid #73AD21;
  margin: 2px;
  overflow: hidden;   
  background-color: rgb(245, 245, 245);
}

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
  
   }

.column p{
       text-align: justify; 
}

.column h2{
  color:  rgb(183, 255, 0);;  
margin: 0;
padding-top: 14px;
}


@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .column {
    width: 100%;
    }
      }
```

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
<title>My Webpage</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 </head>

    <body>
        <div class="header">
            <h1>Header</h1>
            <p>orem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas sit amet pretium urna. Vivamus</p>
        </div>

        <div class="navigation">
            <ul>
                <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <main>
            <div class="row">
            <div class="column">
                <h2>Column</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas sit amet pretium urna. Vivamus venenatis velit nec neque ultricies, eget elementum magna tristique. Quisque vehicula, risus eget aliquam placerat, purus leo tincidunt eros, eget luctus quam orci in velit. Praesent scelerisque tortor sed accumsan convallis.</p>
            </div>

            <div class="column">
                <h2>Column</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas sit amet pretium urna. Vivamus venenatis velit nec neque ultricies, eget elementum magna tristique. Quisque vehicula, risus eget aliquam placerat, purus leo tincidunt eros, eget luctus quam orci in velit. Praesent scelerisque tortor sed accumsan convallis.</p>
            </div>

            <div class="column">
                <h2>Column</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas sit amet pretium urna. Vivamus venenatis velit nec neque ultricies, eget elementum magna tristique. Quisque vehicula, risus eget aliquam placerat, purus leo tincidunt eros, eget luctus quam orci in velit. Praesent scelerisque tortor sed accumsan convallis.</p>
            </div>
        </div>


        </main>


        
    </body>
</html>
```

if you are not satisfied with this answer, you need to study **Media Queries** to make your website Responsive or use simple col and row rules. and one more thing you can use BootStrap formwork.
I hope, I helped you.

Comment: thats actually pretty slick, what did you exactly do? And yeah, i've heard about bootstraps, thats  my next mission to learn. At the  moment i want to be able to really really really really be able to make a dead-basic website by hand coding. Thanks for the help